# Angular alternative to setInterval()

Tags: angular, typescript

I use the following method changing a property after a certain amount of time:

```
switchColors() {
    this.interval = setInterval( () => {
      some code;
    }, 700);
}
```

**It works, but sometime this approach seems to be unreliable in terms of flickering, jumping etc.**

Is there another, better way to achieve a similar behavior?

Comment: `interval` is indeed an alternative to `setInterval`, does that suffice? It sounds like you might still run into a flicker issue.

Comment: @JasonAwbrey Kind of. If I leave the tab for a while and come back, it sometimes seems to be sped up - is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: As far as this question is concerned for SO, i'd agree that the RxJS `interval` is a sufficient alternative to `setInterval`. I think to dig into the other issues you're experiencing they would fit better into a new question with some more code examples. If you open that up feel free to ping me in a comment on there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`interval`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/interval).

```
import {interval} from 'rxjs';
```

```
switchColors() {
    this.intervalSubscription = interval(700).subscribe(() => {
      some code;
    });
}
```

Note that I changed the field name in the assignment from `interval` to `intervalSubscription` so it is not confused with the import `interval` (there is no naming collision, it is strictly for read-ability).

Comment: Thank you, but if I leave the tab for a while and come back, it sometimes kind of seems to be sped up - is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Clear the interval when you leave the page, in a `ngOnDestroy` or some similar method then re-declare the interval on returning to that page that has helped me in the past when facing a similar issue. @Tim

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Timer Observable from rxjs, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50455468/1913371):

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

oberserableTimer() {
    const source = timer(1000, 2000);
    const abc = source.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val, '-');
      this.subscribeTimer = this.timeLeft - val;
    });
  }

<p (click)="oberserableTimer()">Start Observable timer</p> {{subscribeTimer}}
```